# Микросервисы. Event drive. Получение данных из другого сервиса

Tags: java, c#, backend, микросервисы

Есть микросервис А, он генерит событие которое содержит поля (id,name,age), микросервис B получает это событие и забирает себе только id, остальные данные в контексте сервиса B ненужны. Затем, сервис B генерит событие которое содержит только id и его получает сервис C, но ему нужны данные сервиса A (name,age). Как сервису C получить данные сервиса А?

Понятно что можно просто сделать из С grpc в А. Интересует подход именно event drive.
Так же сервис С не может слушать сервис А и дублировать у себя инфу, так как в контексте сервиса С не нужны все сущности А а только которые отправит В.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Синзронный вызов тут сам напрашивается, но если хотите себе сложностей, то пусть С генерит событие, которое ловит А и после А генерит событие, которое ловит С.

Comment: если С интересуют только события В, а В поля name,age не интересны, то и С эти поля не интересны, иначе С должно говорить с А

Comment: ym32167 плохого не посоветует...

Comment: @ ym32167 про синхронный вызов это понятно, просто весь интернет говорит про event drive архитектуру, типа сервисы внутри должны общаться через события, типа это дает преимущество в слабой связности сервисов. Но кейс который я отписал настолько банальный, странно что ничего нет об этом в интернетах, искал долго, везде простые примеры.

Comment: @ym32167 Возможно криво описал кейс, если кратко, сервису С чтоб создать сущность для дальнейшей своей работы в своем контексте нужны данные из А, но реагирует он на сообщение от В в контексте которого нет нужных данных. Это ж обычная стандартная ситуация )

Comment: Получается в такой ситуации нужно выдумывать проброс сообщения от В через А и С уже слушать А, но по бизнес процессу это прям костыль. Да я понимаю сложно без реального примера. Просто свой описывать это будет сложно. Попробую придумать пример близкий но легкий для понимания

Comment: Есть три сервиса, А - ученики , В - школа номер 15, C - отчисленные ученики, при сборе всех доков и определения куда поступит ученик сервис А кидает событие ´Ученик готов зачислению´. Сервис В ловит это событие, понимает что этот ученик в его школу и зачисляет к себе (сохраняет его id) , потом только школа может отчислить, т.е сервис В кидает событие ‘отчислен’ , сервис С ловит отчисленных и чтоб его создать у себя для дальнейшей работы ему нужны документы из А )

Comment: что же это никто никак не может ник мой написать =) Меня вызвать вот так можно @tym32167

Comment: Архитектура существует, чтобы решать конкретные задачи. Если вы пихаете архитектуру с событиями просто потому что кто то что то говорит в интернете - то вы не знаете что делаете по сути.

Comment: `Получается в такой ситуации нужно выдумывать проброс сообщения от В через А и С` вообще то я написал как раз простивоположное. Это что, назначение B отдавать данные про name/age? Нет. Вот и делать он это не должен

Comment: Ваш пример нерабочий, так как сервис "Ученики" не может говорить кто куда готов зачисляться, это работа сервиса "Школа". Сервис отчисленных тоже смысла не имеет, так как отчисление/зачисление - это история операций в школе. То есть из вашего примера должен быть 1) сервис реестр учеников 2) сервис школа, который из сервиса реестра только данные учеников получает, и делает всю остальную работу

Comment: Школ может быть много , школа 15, школа 17 итд . Внутри каждой школы свой процесс зачисления ученика, своя логика зачисления и отчисления и всего остального, это явно разные сервисы. Сервис Учеников - А который, это сервис всех абитуриентов, возможно не правильно назвал, в сервисе А происходит всякая подготовительная логика к зачислению в школы. Сервис С - отчисленные, там общая логика работы с отчисленными учениками всех школ) понятно что пример выдуман и не идеален, может заменить учеников на заказы а школы на компании а отчисленных в товары на возврат @tym32167

Comment: Если вы для каждой школы пишете свой сервис, то у вас уже проблемы масштабирования. При этом "подлготовка быть абитуриентом", "быть отчисленным" - это действия, связанные с логикой школы, а значит должно быть частью сервиса школы, особенно если у каждой школы свой процесс для абитуриентов и один человек может быть абитуриентом в одних школах и отчисленным в других.

Comment: @tym32167 Вы интегратор школ), каждая школа выдает своё api для взаимодействия с ней, в каждой школе, несмотря на схожесть процессов (зачисление, отчисление, выдача дневника ученика), внутри алгоритмы этих процессов разные, так же нагрузка в разных школах разная, в одной учится 5 учеников в другой 35кк . Как раз разбиение этих школ на сервис дает механизм масштабирования разных школ . где нужен один сервис, где-то 10.

Comment: для вашей системы факт наличия сторонних АПИ для интеграции - это просто деталь реализации. Сегодня другие школы предоставляют АПИ, завтра вы напишете унифицированный процесс и школы перейдут на него - это все просто внутрянка вашего сервиса школ, деталь его реализации.